# What is cb in multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

In the code below, from the multer API, both the destination and filename options are anonymous functions. Both of these functions have an argument called *cb*. Are these callback functions defined in the multer module somewhere or am I supposed to supply them?

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }
```

Comment: Great Question .. it is really unclear

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is: yes cb is provided by multer. And yes, it's weird documentation says nothing about it.
This callback is a so called error-first function, thus when examining the **req**, or **file** you may decide, that user uploaded something wrong, pass **new Error()** as first argument, and it will be returned in response. Note though, that it will raise an unhandled exception in your app. So I prefer to always pass null and handle user input in the corresponding controller.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const error = file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
      ? null
      : new Error('wrong file');
    cb(error, '/if-no-error-upload-file-to-this-directory');
  },
  //same for filename
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Note : I don't know what is multer

lets say you have a function,

```
 function destination(req, files){
    //something happen here
 }
```

Now in your code you call this function with two arguments

```
destination(req, files);
```

And now if you need to immediately execute another function after completion of the above function, you need to have a callback function.
Lets say you need to `console.log('Hello world')` after completion of the destination function,

```
destination(req, files , function(){
    console.log('hello world')
});
```

I am sure you know this kind of functions. Now the problem is destination function only accept 2 arguments so we need to add another argument to function definition. Lets call the third argument as 'cb'

```
 function destination(req, files, cb){
    //something happen here
 }
```

Now what is the type of cb should be? It should be a function. isn't it?
so if the third argument is a function then we have to execute this cb function in somewhere. The best place to execute the cb function is after the all the code inside the destination function.

```
 function destination(req, files, cb){
    //something happen here
    cb();
 }
```

And here we have a callback function!! If you think deeply you will understand why they introduced javaScript Promises

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You provide the callback.

cb is a callback function that accepts 2 parameters.

you can see this in a usage scenario for either of the methods. Such as...

```
let req = true;
let file = 'MyFile.txt';
function myCallbackFunc = function(value1, value2){ console.log('my callback function'); };
storage.filename(req, file, myCallbackFunc));
```

Please understand that I do not know what the "req" or "file" parameters should look like so I just made up something for the example.

Comment: In the code I quoted from the API both the destination and filename use cb. In a real situation presumably two different functions with different names would be required like destinationCb and filenameCb?

Comment: In this context, cb is an instance variable for that function. "cb" for one method is not the same as "cb" for the other because it's defined when the function is called.

Comment: Reading the documentation for Multer, it appears that they are providing the callback for you to handle files in storage. You call storage.destination() and the callback is the code that executes and includes the information about the file you need to do what you want with the file in storage. The callback appears optional.

Comment: So I can either leave it as cb and a function in the multer module will be used or I can define my own function with a different name and use that instead?

Comment: I need to read a lot more about Multer to fully understand what they are doing here. The code is to config the destination and filename for a file that is being uploaded, but I have not seen an example using these methods directly. Which is probably why you are asking if you need to supply the callback or if the API does it. At this point, I can't answer that.

Comment: I am struggling with a number of things and it always seems to come back to callbacks in the end. I kind of understand simple examples but in the context of something like multer I end up confused.